# Debug a windows service entry without windbg

Tags: kernel-mode, x64dbg, windows-10

An [answer to a similar question here](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/10910/reversing-a-windows-service) mentions that the entry of a windows service can be patched to allow attaching a debugger (in my case x64dbg). Google searches on the topic are all related to setting a breakpoint in the source.

I'd like to know how exactly this is done when only a binary is available.

I'm trying to port a windows service to Linux. I'm not very familiar with the windows OS. While I can step through normal routines, the service probes the hardware and sets up a few global values. For this reason I need to know exactly what is being sent/received during its initialization.

I did try `windbg` but found it to be very difficult to use when no source code is present.

Comment: Does x64dbg support kernel level debugging like windbg?

Answer (score 7):

I'll post my own answer here so I can find this again in the future.

1. Using [CFF Explorer](https://ntcore.com/?page_id=388) open the service binary.
2. Find the `AddressOfEntryPoint` in the `Optional Header`.
3. Find the `.text` entry in `Section Headers`.
4. Calculate `raw_offset = raw_address - virtual_address + AddressOfEntryPoint`.
5. Within the built-in hex editor, navigate to `raw_address`.
6. Change the two bytes there to `EB FE`.
7. Save and exit.
8. Modify `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\ServicesPipeTimeout` to `0xFFFFFFFF` (requires reboot).
9. Replace service with patched version and start (its status should become 'starting').
10. In `x64dbg` check `Enable Debug Privilege`, restart `x64dbg`.
11. Attach to the service.
12. Replace the `EB FE` bytes with their original values.
13. The entry point can now be debugged.

Other notes - `x64dbg` will not stop at the entry point of a running service. Use the command `:EntryPoint` to display its address and scroll into view.